# Server Management Studio visual editor

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there any way to add/edit/remove rows in MS SQL Server Management Studio as it is possible with phpMyAdmin ? I mean is there any gui to list rows, edit them and add, or do I have to do all operations using SQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Object Explorer.   Expand the Databases, database, table, then Edit Top 200 rows.   If you want more rows, I believe you can edit the Top property in the right window.

If you need more direct table editing, I think Access might be an alternative.

Comment: You can set default number of retrieved rows in `Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Commands`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit or delete specific rows in a table, not just the top 200 rows, right-click on the Views folder and select "New View...".  In the View Designer pane, add the table you want to work with, and set the criteria you want to filter by.  When you click the execute button, the returned rows will appear in an editable grid, where you can edit or delete them using an excel-like interface.